# How to auto-select the APN depending on SIM card?

Tags: gsm, at-command

I have this GSM embedded device under linux, where depending on external factors I might chose to put a different sim card into. But in the configuration for the PPP, I have to give an APN, which changes depending on the network du jour. How can I automatize that?

It just downed on me that smartphones don't need explicit APN entry to work when changing the sim card (also, the APN is sometimes different in M2M and actual cell phone, not sure I can use the same trick).

(I know you are curious: it's deployed in the middle of nowhere, and we chose the least worst network at the last minute on the installation site)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect the network operator from the IMSI of the SIM, and have in your device a table mapping operators to APNs.

There are several sites that will provide you an IMSI to operator listing or MCC and MNC to operator listing. The MCC (Mobile Country One) is the first three digits of the IMIS and the MNC (Mobile Network code) the next 2 or 3 digits. Some example links:

- https://www.imei.info/carriers/
- https://www.mcc-mnc.com

As an aside, if you want to be able to change to adapt to the best available network coverage over time, the way many M2M applications achieve this is to use a 'forgein' SIM which can then roam to the best available signal at a given time. If your data usage requirements are low this can be a good way to avoid being dependent on one operator in an area with poor coverage. There are quite a few companies who specialise in these type of M2M sims, depending on your target location.

Comment: Thanks, we are in a bind with data usage, we're doing things like 1 or 2Go a month, so cost is an issue (M2M sim cards are expensive, and we can't use normal ones, it's forbidden and enforced)

Comment: The link is no more. Do you have a copy ?

Comment: @mrid - updated with some working examples and some info on how to look up from an iMSI.